# Get whole string from a couple of letters using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Does anyone know how to get the full name from just the first 3 letters using xslt 1.0?

```
<node>
    <name>Shelly</name>
    <name>Roger</name>
    <name>Tommy</name>
    <name>Ginger</name>
</node>
```

For example, I want to be able to loop through the following xml node, and when it loops to a string containing 'tom' (something like: contains(//*name,'tom*'), and output the full name 'Tommy' from the list.

I assume it'll be something like:
for-each //node/name/, find value which contains 'tom', then output (.) that value.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the `starts-with` function. The expression you are looking for is,

```
<xsl:for-each select="node/name[starts-with(., 'Tom')]">
```

Although, you might want to parameterise it, like so...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="name" select="'Tom'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="node/name[starts-with(., $name)]">
          <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note, this is case-sensitive. If you wanted to be case-insensitive, then a little bit more work is needed in XSLT 1.0...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="l" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="u" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:param name="name" select="'tom'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="node/name[starts-with(translate(., $u, $l), translate($name, $u, $l))]">
          <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks Tim. I realized my solution nearly after posting it =)
Thank you for being thorough though... I like your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops... brain fart... it's easy:

```
<xsl:variable name="vSuffix">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='name']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-after(.,'tom')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="concat('tom',$vSuffix)"/>
```

Comment: It may be easy, but it doesn't do what you asked for. -- Note also that your use of `//*[local-name()='name']` instead of `name` suggest you are trying to work around namespaces, instead of using them as intended.

Answer (score 0):

A complete XSLT-1.0 solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="/node/name">
      <xsl:call-template name="NameFromFirstThreeChars">
        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="selText" select="'rog'" />   <!-- example for 'Roger' -->
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="NameFromFirstThreeChars">
      <xsl:param name="node" />
      <xsl:param name="selText" />
      <xsl:variable name="upperSel" select="translate($selText,$lower,$upper)" />
      <xsl:if test="starts-with(translate($node,$lower,$upper), $upperSel)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$node" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This solution performs a transformation from lowercase letters to uppercase letters and then compares the first three(or whatever you like) chars with the parameter `$selText`. If this is a match, it returns the (`text()`) value of the `$node` variable.

The `xsl:template` named `NameFromFirstThreeChars` is universally applicable with the two parameters `node` and `selText`.